# С#. Запрос/ответ к Web сервису через XML

Tags: c#, .net, веб-программирование, soap

Здравствуйте. Столкнулся с проблемой неверного тех.задания. для программы на C#.  В тех задании ошибочно указанно что на сервере поднята SOAP служба и приведен формат запроса и ответа к службе в XML формате. Но XML не соответствует SOAP формату. При уточнении было выяснено что нужно просто отправлять XML файл на сервер и ожидать от него ответа тоже XML файлом.

> Для  нормативного расписания  интерфейс WEB сервера
>   GetScheduleNormative4Place.

пример запроса:

```
<?xmlversion="1.0" encoding=" utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <Authentication User=’ddd’ Password=’samba’/>
   <Place ESR=’34567’/>
</root>
```

Генерировать XML и парсить ответ я смогу. эту часть уже оттестировал. Меня интересует именно сам сетевой обмен через что его делать?

На ум приходит использовать webclient.

Comment: а там не WCF случайно? Для него это вполне штатный режим работать по http биндингу и методы по контракту предоставлять. Вы можете выполнить этот запрос из обычного браузера? что возвращает?

Comment: А не multipart там? Тогда столкнетесь с boundary... Я делал на System.Net WebResponse response, чтобы охватить все фарймворки на всякий случай.

Comment: для выполнения запроса из браузера мне нужно указать "ip:port/GetScheduleNormative4Place" ?

Comment: думаю что там не WCF. знаю только что они XML файлами обмениваются и интерфейс предоставляют для каждого типа запроса.